Error when using `\DTLdisplaydb` to display a custom database created inside a `tabular` environment
I am working with the datatool package in LaTeX to create and display a custom database. I define a new database (DBnew), add a column to it, and populate it with values calculated from another database (DBfile). The data is added to DBnew inside a tabular environment. However, when I try to display the contents of DBnew using \DTLdisplaydb{DBnew}, I encounter an error.
Here is the code snippet I am using:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{DBfile.txt}
colA,colB
a,1
b,2
c,3
\end{filecontents}

% Load the database from the file 'DBfile.txt' into a database named 'DBfile'.
\DTLloaddb{DBfile}{DBfile.txt}

\begin{document}
    
    % Create a new, empty database named 'DBnew'.
    \DTLnewdb{DBnew} 
    
    % Add a new column named 'result' to the 'DBnew' database.
    \DTLaddcolumn{DBnew}{result}
    
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        \DTLforeach{DBfile}{\COL=colB}
        {\\
         % Print the value of \COL (i.e., the current row's 'colB' value) on a new line.
         \COL
         % Calculate a new value by adding 1 to \COL and store it in \RESULT.
         \FPeval\RESULT{\COL+1}
         % Add a new row to the 'DBnew' database.
         \DTLnewrow{DBnew}
         % Add the calculated \RESULT to the 'result' column of the new row in 'DBnew'.
         \DTLnewdbentry{DBnew}{result}{\RESULT} 
        }
    \end{tabular}
    
    % Uncomment the line below to display the contents of the 'DBnew' database in the document.
    % Note: Uncommenting the following line may result in an error.
    %\DTLdisplaydb{DBnew}

\end{document}

ERROR:
Error that occurs when uncommenting the line %\DTLdisplaydb{DBnew}
! Undefined control sequence.
\@dtl@val ->\RESULT 
                    
l.41    \DTLdisplaydb{DBnew}
                          
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


Unrelated, but the filecontents package isn't necessary anymore. The filecontents environment is now part of LaTeX kernel.

I don't know datatool, but here the error is raised because \RESULT is defined inside the tabular environment and you need it outside (by default, all TeX definitions are local).
You can add
\global\let\RESULT\RESULT

inside the tabular. You'll get

No error, but I think it's not the desired output.
You need instead to expand \RESULT in \DTLnewdbentry. With modern LaTeX you can use ExpandArgs
\ExpandArgs {nne} \DTLnewdbentry{DBnew}{result}{\RESULT}

This will expand the third argument (\RESULT).
Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents}{DBfile.txt}
colA,colB
a,1
b,2
c,3
\end{filecontents}

% Load the database from the file 'DBfile.txt' into a database named 'DBfile'.
\DTLloaddb{DBfile}{DBfile.txt}

\begin{document}

% Create a new, empty database named 'DBnew'.
\DTLnewdb{DBnew}

% Add a new column named 'result' to the 'DBnew' database.
\DTLaddcolumn{DBnew}{result}

\begin{tabular}{l}
  \DTLforeach{DBfile}{\COL=colB}
  {\\
    % Print the value of \COL (i.e., the current row's 'colB' value) on a new line.
  \COL
  % Calculate a new value by adding 1 to \COL and store it in \RESULT.
  \FPeval\RESULT{\COL+1}
  % Add a new row to the 'DBnew' database.
  \DTLnewrow{DBnew}
  % Add the calculated \RESULT to the 'result' column of the new row in 'DBnew'.
  \ExpandArgs {nne} \DTLnewdbentry{DBnew}{result}{\RESULT}
  }
\end{tabular}

\DTLdisplaydb{DBnew}

\end{document}



Thx for your answer. What does {nne} mean? Best regards

@MarcoMoldenhauer This is LaTeX3 syntax, documented in the LaTeX3 interface. n is a token between braces let unexpanded (so it's do nothing here), e means a full expansion. There is also o for one level expansion.
